# What are std::filebuf equivalent of ifstream::eof ::fail and ::tellg

Tags: c++

Is there any equivalent to following functions if using `std::filebuf`? :

```
std::ifstream::eof
std::ifstream::fail
std::ifstream::tellg
```

If yes, which?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't any. Those things relate to *streams*, not the data buffer used by those streams.

The entire purpose of `std::ifstream` is to add features like that on top of the `std::filebuf`.